# Python Pandas dataset filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to access `my_data.iloc[j:i] == my_data.at['sales]`. ie, `[0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [3,1]` This kind of element access needs filters out dataset.

I have written code as:

```
x = 1
j = 0
result = []
for i in range(len(my_data)) :
   if (my_data.iloc[j:i] == my_data.at['sales'])
       # if equal then append the row
      result.append(my_data.iloc[i, :])
      j = j + 1
```

I get `ValueError the truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. use an empty, a.bool()`... please help me out.. thanks

new info:

when I printed that list orientation, this is the result .

```
{'lndex' : [1,1,1,1,1],'table' ,' table1' ,'table2','table3','table4'],'Table Value Index' :[0,0,0,0,0], 'Value_Index' : [1,2,3,4,5]} ...
```

still the code didnt work for me. i will post the code and error ...

code:

```
for index,row in my_data.iterrows():
if (my_data.at[index,1] == my_data.at['Index']:  #error line
    result.append(my_data.iloc[index,:])
```

it gives key Error(key) from err on error line. i am stepping thru the code to understand what is going one... please help

Comment: Please can you provide the output `print(my_data.head().to_dict('list'))`?

Comment: when I printed that list orientation, this is the result . 
'code'{'lndex' : [1,1,1,1,1],'table' ,' table1' ,'table2','table3','table4'],'Table Value Index' :[0,0,0,0,0], 'Value_Index' : [1,2,3,4,5]} ... 'code'

so is it still two arrays? still the code didnt work for me. i will post the code and error ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'v1': [0,1,2,3,5], 'v2': [1,1,1,1,1]})
x = np.array([[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1]])
# so basically first 4 rows of the DF should match the X
if df.iloc[0:4].values.all() == x.all():
    print('Match')
else:
    print('Mismatch')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code. the 1 st index column of 'sales' on pandas dataset that i need to compare with [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] element

Comment: I think I have given you the solution... I presume you want to compare two arrays.. so the code above does it.

Comment: do I really have to  move the df to np.array() like the above code? there is no other way because i do have a large dataset and not certain about [n.n] last row ?

Comment: Under the hood df is a numpy array. Create df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'v1': np.random.random(100000000), 'v2': np.random.random(100000000)}) and then st = datetime.datetime.now()
xx = df.values
ed = datetime.datetime.now()
ed - st
it is only 250 micro seconds